# value_ptr<T> - a C++11 header-only, deep-copying smart pointer that preserves value semantics for polymorphic and undefined types (updated)

Tags: c++, c++11, library, pointers

My previous iteration was [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/168920/23790).  I've since finalized the concept as described in the title, and would appreciate any feedback

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/clunietp/value_ptr/)

Introduction:

`value_ptr` is a C++11 header only, deep-copying smart pointer that preserves value semantics for both polymorphic and undefined types. `value_ptr` aims to address the following issues by reducing/eliminating the boilerplate needed to facilitate value semantics: The polymorphic copy problem, and the undefined type problem.

The polymorphic copy problem. Given a class hierarchy, preserve value semantics while preventing object slicing.

Example:

Without `value_ptr`:

```
struct Base { virtual Base* clone() const { return new Base(*this); } };  
struct Derived : Base { Base* clone() const { return new Derived(*this); };

struct MyAwesomeClass {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> foo;
};

int main() {
    MyAwesomeClass a{};
    // lets make a copy of a
    auto b = a; // ERROR.  Now we have to do a bunch of boilerplate to clone 'foo', etc.  Boo!
}
```

With `value_ptr`:

```
#include "value_ptr.hpp"
struct Base { virtual Base* clone() const { return new Base(*this); } };  
struct Derived : Base { Base* clone() const { return new Derived(*this); };

struct MyAwesomeClass {
    smart_ptr::value_ptr<Base> foo;
};

int main() {
    MyAwesomeClass a{};
    // lets make a copy of a
    auto b = a; // no boilerplate, no slicing, no problem.  yay!
}
```

The undefined type problem. Given a declared-but-not-yet defined type (which may or may not be polymorphic), preserve value semantics and prevent object slicing.
This problem is often seen in the PIMPL idiom and often associated with forward declared classes.

Example:

Without `value_ptr`:

```
struct U;   // undefined type, defined in another file somewhere that we can't/don't want to include
class MyAwesomeClass {
    std::unique_ptr<U> u; // unique_ptr doesn't really fit, but we don't want to manage a raw pointer either.
};

MyAwesomeClass a{};
auto b = a; // ERROR C2280!
```

With `value_ptr`:

```
struct U;   // undefined type
class MyAwesomeClass {
    smart_ptr::value_ptr<U> u;
};

MyAwesomeClass a{};
auto b = a; // no problem!
```

Features:

- Header only, single file, cross platform, no dependencies outside the STL
- Compatible interface/convertible to `std::unique_ptr`
- Space efficient:

  - Utilizes empty base optimization to minimize memory footprint
  - defined types: `sizeof( value_ptr ) == sizeof(T*) == sizeof(std::unique_ptr)`
  - Undefined types: `sizeof( value_ptr ) == sizeof(T*)` + two function pointers
- Polymorphic copying:

  - Automatically detects/utilizes `clone()` member function
- Static assertion prevents object slicing if a user-defined copier not provided or clone member not found
- Support for stateful and stateless deleters and copiers, via functors or lambdas
- Unit tested, valgrind clean

The code:

```
#ifndef SMART_PTR_VALUE_PTR
#define SMART_PTR_VALUE_PTR

#include <memory>       // unique_ptr
#include <functional>   // less_equal
#include <cassert>      // assert

#if defined( _MSC_VER)  

#if (_MSC_VER >= 1915)  // constexpr tested/working _MSC_VER 1915 (vs17 15.8)
#define VALUE_PTR_CONSTEXPR constexpr
#else   // msvc 15 bug prevents constexpr in some cases
#define VALUE_PTR_CONSTEXPR
#endif

//  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/optimizing-the-layout-of-empty-base-classes-in-vs2015-update-2-3/
#define USE_EMPTY_BASE_OPTIMIZATION __declspec(empty_bases) // requires vs2015 update 2 or later.  still needed vs2017

#else
#define VALUE_PTR_CONSTEXPR constexpr 
#define USE_EMPTY_BASE_OPTIMIZATION
#endif

namespace smart_ptr {

    namespace detail {

        // void_t for c++11
        //  from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t
        template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type; };
        template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

        // is_incomplete<T>, based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/39816909
        template <class, class = void> struct is_incomplete : std::true_type {};
        template <class T> struct is_incomplete<
            T
            , typename std::enable_if<std::is_object<T>::value && !std::is_pointer<T>::value && (sizeof(T) > 0)>::type
            >
            : std::false_type
        {};

        // has clone() method detection
        template<class T, class = void> struct has_clone : std::false_type {};
        template<class T> struct has_clone<T, decltype(void(std::declval<T>().clone()))> : std::true_type {};

        // Returns flag if test passes (false==slicing is probable)
        // T==base pointer, U==derived/supplied pointer
        template <typename T, typename U, bool IsDefaultCopier>
        struct slice_test : std::integral_constant<bool, 
            std::is_same<T, U>::value   // if U==T, no need to check for slicing
            || std::is_same<std::nullptr_t, U>::value   // nullptr is fine
            || !IsDefaultCopier // user provided cloner, assume they're handling it
            || has_clone<typename std::remove_pointer<U>::type>::value  // using default cloner, clone method must exist in U
        >::type 
        {};

        // ptr_data:  holds pointer, deleter, copier
        //  pointer and deleter held in unique_ptr member, this struct is derived from copier to minimize overall footprint
        //  uses EBCO to solve sizeof(value_ptr<T>) == sizeof(T*) problem
        template <typename T, typename Deleter, typename Copier>
            struct 
            USE_EMPTY_BASE_OPTIMIZATION
            ptr_data
            : public Copier
        {

            using unique_ptr_type = std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>;
            using pointer = typename unique_ptr_type::pointer;
            using deleter_type = typename unique_ptr_type::deleter_type;
            using copier_type = Copier;

            unique_ptr_type uptr;

            ptr_data() = default;

            template <typename Dx, typename Cx>
            constexpr ptr_data( T* px, Dx&& dx, Cx&& cx )
                : copier_type( std::forward<Cx>(cx) )
                , uptr(px, std::forward<Dx>(dx))
            {}

            ptr_data( ptr_data&& ) = default;
            ptr_data& operator=( ptr_data&& ) = default;

            constexpr ptr_data( const ptr_data& that )
                : ptr_data( that.clone() )
            {}

            ptr_data& operator=( const ptr_data& that ) {
                if ( this != &that )
                    *this = that.clone();
                return *this;
            }

            // get_copier, analogous to std::unique_ptr<T>::get_deleter()
            copier_type& get_copier() { return *this; }

            // get_copier, analogous to std::unique_ptr<T>::get_deleter()
            const copier_type& get_copier() const { return *this; }

            ptr_data clone() const {
                // get a copier, use it to clone ptr, construct/return a ptr_data
                return{ 
                    (T*)this->get_copier()(this->uptr.get())
                    , this->uptr.get_deleter()
                    , this->get_copier() 
                };
            }

        };  // ptr_data

        // ptr_base:    value_ptr base class
        //  holds ptr_data
        template <typename T, typename Deleter, typename Copier>
        struct ptr_base {

            using deleter_type = Deleter;
            using copier_type = Copier;
            using _data_type = ptr_data<T, deleter_type, copier_type>;

            _data_type _data;

            using pointer = typename _data_type::pointer;
            using unique_ptr_type = std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>;

            template <typename Px, typename Dx, typename Cx>
            constexpr ptr_base( Px&& px, Dx&& dx, Cx&& cx )
                : _data(
                    std::forward<Px>( px )
                    , std::forward<Dx>( dx )
                    , std::forward<Cx>(cx)
                )
            {}

            // return unique_ptr
            const unique_ptr_type& uptr() const & {
                return this->_data.uptr;
            }

            // return unique_ptr
            unique_ptr_type& uptr() & {
                return this->_data.uptr;
            }

            // conversion to unique_ptr, ref qualified
            operator unique_ptr_type const&() const & {
                return this->uptr();
            }

            // conversion to unique_ptr, ref qualified
            operator unique_ptr_type& () & {
                return this->uptr();
            }

            deleter_type& get_deleter() { return this->uptr().get_deleter(); }
            const deleter_type& get_deleter() const { return this->uptr().get_deleter(); }

            copier_type& get_copier() { return this->_data.get_copier(); }
            const copier_type& get_copier() const { return this->_data.get_copier(); }

        };  // ptr_base

        // wraps a functor (Op), intercepts calls to Op::operator(), and forwards the call to the specified delegate
        //  this is a smallest-footprint dynamic dispatch approach to handling (potentially) incomplete types
        //  delegate should have the signature: result( [const] functor_wrapper<...>& (or [const] Op&), params... (from Op::operator()) )
        //  inheriting from Op to minimize sizeof(functor_wrapper)
        template <typename Op, typename Delegate>
        struct
            functor_wrapper
            : public Op 
        {           
            // delegate function to call
            Delegate delegate_;

            // construct with Op, Delegate
            template <typename Op_, typename Delegate_>
            constexpr functor_wrapper( Op_&& op, Delegate_&& del)
                : Op(std::forward<Op>(op))
                , delegate_(std::forward<Delegate>(del))
            {}

            // invoked for event, const
            template <typename... Args>
            auto operator()(Args&&... args) const -> typename std::result_of<Op(Args...)>::type {
                if (this->delegate_ == nullptr)
                    throw std::bad_function_call();
                return this->delegate_( *this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);    //  call delegate, with reference to this as first parameter
            }

            // invoked for event
            template <typename... Args>
            auto operator()(Args&&... args) -> typename std::result_of<Op(Args...)>::type {
                if (this->delegate_ == nullptr)
                    throw std::bad_function_call();
                return this->delegate_( *this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);    //  call delegate, with const reference to this as first parameter
            }

        };  // functor_wrapper

        // ptr_base_incomplete: intermediate base class for incomplete types
        //  wraps copy and delete ops in functor wrappers to handle incomplete types
        template <typename T, typename DeleteOp, typename CopyOp
            , typename Deleter = functor_wrapper<DeleteOp, void(*)(const DeleteOp&, T*)>
            , typename Copier = functor_wrapper<CopyOp, T*(*)(const CopyOp&, const T*)>
        >
            struct ptr_base_incomplete
            : ptr_base<T, Deleter, Copier> {

            using base_type = ptr_base<T, Deleter, Copier>;
            using pointer = typename base_type::pointer;

            // default construct for incomplete type
            template <typename Dx, typename Cx>
            constexpr ptr_base_incomplete(std::nullptr_t, Dx&& dx, Cx&& cx)
                : base_type(
                    nullptr
                    , Deleter(std::forward<Dx>(dx), [](const DeleteOp&, T* ptr) { assert(ptr == nullptr); })
                    , Copier(std::forward<Cx>(cx), [](const CopyOp&, const T* ptr) -> T* { assert(ptr == nullptr); return nullptr; })
                )
            {}

            template <typename Dx, typename Cx>
            constexpr ptr_base_incomplete(pointer px, Dx&& dx, Cx&& cx)
                : base_type(
                    px
                    , Deleter(std::forward<Dx>(dx), [](const DeleteOp& op, T* ptr) { op(ptr); } )
                    , Copier(std::forward<Cx>(cx), [](const CopyOp& op, const T* ptr) -> T* { return op(ptr); } )
                )
            {}

        };  // ptr_base_incomplete

    }   // detail

    template <typename T>
    struct 
        USE_EMPTY_BASE_OPTIMIZATION
        default_copy {

    private:
        struct _clone_tag {};
        struct _copy_tag {};

        T* operator()(const T* what, _clone_tag) const {
            return what->clone();
        }

        T* operator()(const T* what, _copy_tag) const {
            return new T(*what);
        }   // _copy

    public:
        // copy operator
        T* operator()( const T* what ) const {

            if ( !what )
                return nullptr;

            // tag dispatch on has_clone
            return this->operator()( what
                , typename std::conditional<detail::has_clone<T>::value, _clone_tag, _copy_tag>::type() 
                );
        }   // operator()

    };  // default_copy

    template <typename T
        , typename Deleter = std::default_delete<T>
        , typename Copier = default_copy<T>
        , typename Base = 
            typename std::conditional<detail::is_incomplete<T>::value, 
                detail::ptr_base_incomplete<T, Deleter, Copier>
                , detail::ptr_base<T, Deleter, Copier>
            >::type
    >
        struct value_ptr 
            : Base
        {
            using base_type = Base;
            using element_type = T;

            using pointer = typename base_type::pointer;
            using const_pointer = const pointer;

            using reference = typename std::add_lvalue_reference<element_type>::type;
            using const_reference = const reference;

            using deleter_type = Deleter;
            using copier_type = Copier;

            // construct with pointer, deleter, copier
            template <typename Px>
            constexpr value_ptr( Px px, deleter_type dx, copier_type cx )
                : base_type( px
                    , std::move( dx )
                    , std::move( cx )
                )
            {
                static_assert(
                    detail::slice_test<pointer, Px, std::is_same<default_copy<T>, copier_type>::value>::value
                    , "value_ptr; clone() method not detected and not using custom copier; slicing may occur"
                    );
            }

            // construct with pointer, deleter
            template <typename Px>
            VALUE_PTR_CONSTEXPR
            value_ptr( Px px, deleter_type dx )
                : value_ptr( px, std::move(dx), copier_type() )
            {}

            // construct with pointer
            template <typename Px>
            VALUE_PTR_CONSTEXPR
            value_ptr( Px px )
                : value_ptr( px, deleter_type(), copier_type() )
            {}

            // construct from unique_ptr, copier
            VALUE_PTR_CONSTEXPR
            value_ptr(std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter> uptr, copier_type copier = copier_type() )
                : value_ptr(uptr.release(), uptr.get_deleter(), std::move(copier) )
            {}

            // std::nullptr_t, default ctor 
            explicit 
            VALUE_PTR_CONSTEXPR
            value_ptr( std::nullptr_t = nullptr )
                : value_ptr( nullptr, deleter_type(), copier_type() )
            {}

            // get pointer
            pointer get() { return this->uptr().get(); }

            // get const pointer
            const_pointer get() const { return this->uptr().get(); }

            // reset pointer
            template <typename Px = std::nullptr_t>
            void reset( Px px = nullptr ) {

                static_assert(
                    detail::slice_test<pointer, Px, std::is_same<default_copy<T>, copier_type>::value>::value
                    , "value_ptr; clone() method not detected and not using custom copier; slicing may occur"
                    );

                *this = value_ptr( px, this->get_deleter(), this->get_copier() );
            }

            // release pointer
            pointer release() {
                return this->uptr().release();
            }   // release

            // return flag if has pointer
            explicit operator bool() const {
                return this->get() != nullptr;
            }

            const_reference operator*() const { return *this->get(); }
            reference operator*() { return *this->get(); }

            const_pointer operator-> () const { return this->get(); }
            pointer operator-> () { return this->get(); }

            void swap( value_ptr& that ) { std::swap( this->_data, that._data ); }

    };// value_ptr

      // non-member swap
    template <class T1, class D1, class C1, class T2, class D2, class C2> void swap( value_ptr<T1, D1, C1>& x, value_ptr<T2, D2, C2>& y ) { x.swap( y ); }

    // non-member operators
    template <class T1, class D1, class C1, class T2, class D2, class C2> bool operator == ( const value_ptr<T1, D1, C1>& x, const value_ptr<T2, D2, C2>& y ) { return x.get() == y.get(); }
    template<class T1, class D1, class C1, class T2, class D2, class C2> bool operator != ( const value_ptr<T1, D1, C1>& x, const value_ptr<T2, D2, C2>& y ) { return x.get() != y.get(); }
    template<class T1, class D1, class C1, class T2, class D2, class C2> bool operator < ( const value_ptr<T1, D1, C1>& x, const value_ptr<T2, D2, C2>& y ) {
        using common_type = typename std::common_type<typename value_ptr<T1, D1, C1>::pointer, typename value_ptr<T2, D2, C2>::pointer>::type;
        return std::less<common_type>()( x.get(), y.get() );
    }
    template<class T1, class D1, class C1, class T2, class D2, class C2> bool operator <= ( const value_ptr<T1, D1, C1>& x, const value_ptr<T2, D2, C2>& y ) { return !( y < x ); }
    template<class T1, class D1, class C1, class T2, class D2, class C2> bool operator >( const value_ptr<T1, D1, C1>& x, const value_ptr<T2, D2, C2>& y ) { return y < x; }
    template<class T1, class D1, class C1, class T2, class D2, class C2> bool operator >= ( const value_ptr<T1, D1, C1>& x, const value_ptr<T2, D2, C2>& y ) { return !( x < y ); }
    template <class T, class D, class C> bool operator == ( const value_ptr<T, D, C>& x, std::nullptr_t ) noexcept { return !x; }
    template <class T, class D, class C> bool operator == ( std::nullptr_t, const value_ptr<T, D, C>& x ) noexcept { return !x; }
    template <class T, class D, class C> bool operator != ( const value_ptr<T, D, C>& x, std::nullptr_t ) noexcept { return (bool)x; }
    template <class T, class D, class C> bool operator != ( std::nullptr_t, const value_ptr<T, D, C>& x ) noexcept { return (bool)x; }
    template <class T, class D, class C> bool operator < ( const value_ptr<T, D, C>& x, std::nullptr_t ) { return std::less<typename value_ptr<T, D, C>::pointer>()( x.get(), nullptr ); }
    template <class T, class D, class C> bool operator<( std::nullptr_t, const value_ptr<T, D, C>& y ) { return std::less<typename value_ptr<T, D, C>::pointer>()( nullptr, y.get() ); }
    template <class T, class D, class C> bool operator <= ( const value_ptr<T, D, C>& x, std::nullptr_t ) { return std::less_equal<typename value_ptr<T, D, C>::pointer>()( x.get(), nullptr ); }
    template <class T, class D, class C> bool operator <= ( std::nullptr_t, const value_ptr<T, D, C>& y ) { return std::less_equal<typename value_ptr<T, D, C>::pointer>()( nullptr, y.get() ); }
    template <class T, class D, class C> bool operator >( const value_ptr<T, D, C>& x, std::nullptr_t ) { return !( nullptr < x ); }
    template <class T, class D, class C> bool operator > ( std::nullptr_t, const value_ptr<T, D, C>& y ) { return !( y < nullptr ); }
    template <class T, class D, class C> bool operator >= ( const value_ptr<T, D, C>& x, std::nullptr_t ) { return !( x < nullptr ); }
    template <class T, class D, class C> bool operator >= ( std::nullptr_t, const value_ptr<T, D, C>& y ) { return !( nullptr < y ); }

    // make value_ptr with default deleter and copier, analogous to std::make_unique
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    value_ptr<T> make_value(Args&&... args) {
        return value_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

    // make a value_ptr from pointer with custom deleter and copier
    template <typename T, typename Deleter = std::default_delete<T>, typename Copier = default_copy<T>>
    static inline auto make_value_ptr(T* ptr, Deleter&& dx = {}, Copier&& cx = {}) -> value_ptr<T, Deleter, Copier> {
        return value_ptr<T, Deleter, Copier>( ptr, std::forward<Deleter>( dx ), std::forward<Copier>(cx) );
    }   // make_value_ptr

}   // smart_ptr ns

#undef VALUE_PTR_CONSTEXPR
#undef USE_EMPTY_BASE_OPTIMIZATION

#endif // !SMART_PTR_VALUE_PTR
```

Comment: This still has (at least) the `_SMART_PTR_VALUE_PTR_` (reserved identifier) and `is_defined` (ephemeral type-trait) and `detect` (overcomplication) that you were told about on the previous review. Do you want to fix those before asking for more reviews? You can fix the code in-place here, as long as nobody's posted a review yet. FWIW, I'm not inclined to re-review it myself until I see some meaningful diffs from the previous version.

Comment: My fault, I derped on the copy/paste from the previous question.  Updated now, thank you

Comment: `void_t` is unused now; and doesn't `is_incomplete` have the same problem as `is_defined`?

Comment: `void_t` -- thanks.  `is_incomplete`, were you suggesting it should be removed?  This makes the whole thing work for one of the use cases I envisioned: value semantics for incomplete types like in the PIMPL use case.  Unless I misunderstood what you were referring to before

Comment: My complaint about `is_incomplete` is that the value of `is_incomplete<T>::value` can be different in two different TUs, which would lead to ODR violations. In fact, its value can *change* over the course of a single TU, which leads to even wackier situations! If you think you need to do something *different* based on the value of `is_incomplete<T>`, I believe you're wrong. But I would be willing to review the code and try to give you a proof-by-construction, if this proof-by-logic leaves you unconvinced.

Comment: @Quuxplusone if you can find a way to break it, please do!  I admit I am having trouble creating a test case which would expose this flaw.  I don't disagree with your logic but I'm having trouble grasping the actual impact in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As promised in the comments, here's a test case that breaks your use of `is_incomplete`.
Two translation units; in one `struct Widget` is incomplete, and in the other it's not. This leads to a different mangled name for `value_ptr<Widget>`, which leads to linker errors when the two translation units are linked together.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/jbEMn5ms5HO7u3dA

Solution: *don't use `is_incomplete`.* Either make it a precondition of your `value_ptr` that it works only on complete types, or make it a guarantee that it works *even* on incomplete types. Don't have it switch its mangling (or its size, or its behavior) based on transient, ephemeral properties such as "completeness."

---

```
    // reset pointer
    template <typename Px = std::nullptr_t>
    void reset( Px px = nullptr ) {
```

I question this function template. You're saying, `reset` should accept *any function argument at all*; but also, if a template argument is provided, then it should default its argument to `nullptr`? So, like,

```
myvalueptr.reset(42);  // OK, dies deep inside
myvalueptr.reset<int*>();  // OK, compiles
```

I would think that a much better way to write the desired overload set would be

```
    template<class Px, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<Px, pointer>>>
    void reset(Px px);  // template accepting just convertible types

    void reset() { reset(nullptr); }  // non-template
```

---

```
    const_reference operator*() const { return *this->get(); }
    reference operator*() { return *this->get(); }
```

This is a very common brain-fart for people implementing pointers and iterators. Just because a *pointer object* is `const`-qualified, doesn't mean the *pointed-to object* is immutable. And just because the pointer object is mutable, doesn't mean the pointed-to object should be mutable!

```
value_ptr<int> vp1 = ...; int& i1 = *vp1;  // OK

const value_ptr<int> vp2 = vp1; int& i2 = *vp2;  // OK!

int& i3 = *value_ptr<int>(vp1);  // OK!
```

Now, the interesting thing in your case is... all three of these cases compile cleanly *anyway*. Why is that?!

```
    using pointer = typename base_type::pointer;
    using const_pointer = const pointer;

    using reference = typename std::add_lvalue_reference<element_type>::type;
    using const_reference = const reference;
```

Aha. I'm actually mildly surprised you got no compiler warning here. Suppose `reference` is `int&`; then what is `const reference`? Well, applying `const` to a reference type doesn't do anything... so your `const_reference` typedef is actually a synonym for `reference`!

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<value_ptr<int>::reference, int&>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<value_ptr<int>::const_reference, int&>);
```

We see the problem more clearly with `const_pointer`:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<value_ptr<int>::pointer, int*>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<value_ptr<int>::const_pointer, int* const>);
```

---

Gotta run now; sorry I found only this unsubtle (if fundamental) issue.

Style-wise, I would say that your line lengths are unnaturally short, which leads to vertically stretched code, which makes it harder to read and review. I'm not sure exactly what I'd do differently; but I'd try to make e.g. the definition of `default_copy` shorter than it currently is, by hook or by crook. The number of lines in a class should somehow reflect its importance in the grand scheme of the code.

---

P.S. to add:

```
template <class T, class D, class C> bool operator >( const value_ptr<T, D, C>& x, std::nullptr_t ) { return !( nullptr < x ); }
```

This is a bug. But also, you should think about ways to reduce the amount of boilerplate associated with these operators. One way to do it would be to give `value_ptr` a base class (not dependent on `D` or `C`) and then provide the comparison operators specifically for that base class. Another way would be to provide a type-trait `is_value_ptr<P>` and then, at global scope, write:

```
template<class T, class U, class = std::enable_if_t<is_value_ptr_v<T> && is_value_ptr<U>>>
bool operator< (const T& t, const U& u) { return t.get() < u.get(); }
template<class T, class U, class = std::enable_if_t<is_value_ptr_v<T> && is_value_ptr<U>>>
bool operator<= (const T& t, const U& u) { return t.get() <= u.get(); }
template<class T, class U, class = std::enable_if_t<is_value_ptr_v<T> && is_value_ptr<U>>>
bool operator> (const T& t, const U& u) { return t.get() > u.get(); }
// ...
```

I would definitely recommend *against* the current spaghetti, and especially against the semi-circular dependency where some `operator<` are implemented in terms of `std::less`.

Comment: `int& i3 = *value_ptr<int>(vp1);  // OK!` Actually, shouldn't `i3` be dangling in this case? You dereference a newly created copy - which won't outlive the statement. (I know that example was for a different problem, but still it throws me off...)

Comment: @hoffmale: You're right, `i3` would be dangling in that case. (But we do expect it to compile anyway.) We could fix the dangle by inventing a function `void use3(int&);` and then asking whether `use3(*value_ptr<int>(vp1))` compiles.

Comment: Please add the test case into the answer, rather than making it reliant on an external site (one that appears to hide the code behind a third-party JavaScript, no less - that's really not very accessible, even while it lasts!).  Thanks.

Comment: You need to `#include "widget.h"` to the top of `widget.cc`, then it compiles.  Looks like the link error is happening because, without `#include "widget.h"`, `Widget` refers to two different types altogether AFAICT thus resulting in the link error

Comment: I added some tests for this particular case and it works fine; but I'm not 100% sure why is_incomplete is still evaluating to 'true' within the impl file.  Is this because `is_incomplete<incomplete_foo>` has already been evaluated to true, and thus the compiler knows to reuse the value of the previous evaluation rather than reevaluate it?    https://github.com/clunietp/value_ptr/commit/a5ca15d0e3cd701cab8992cc66081507acbd9575

Comment: @Tom: "Looks like ... `Widget` refers to two different types altogether AFAICT" — Nope! There is only one `struct Widget` in the program. But the two TUs differ in their opinion of its "incompleteness." As you noticed — "I'm not 100% sure why is_incomplete is still evaluating to 'true' within the impl file" — this leads to very wacky behavior. The fix is _not to change behavior based on the incompleteness of a type._ The STL doesn't do it, and you shouldn't do it either.

Comment: How does `Widget` (defined in `widget.h`) get pulled into the TU for `widget.cc`?  `widget.cc` isn't made aware of the `Widget` in `widget.h`

Comment: @Tom: Imagine that `struct Widget;` is declared in some common header file. We can even refactor my code to make that explicit: https://wandbox.org/permlink/3D7qdBTdSxq5tHfV
I didn't say "compiler bug"; I said "wacky behavior." The compilers are doing exactly what you asked for... but that doesn't mean it's what you wanted!

Comment: Interesting!  But when we add `#include "usewidget.h"` into `usewidget.cc` it works fine.  The plot thickens!

Comment: At this point I'm leaning towards documenting this corner case and leaving `value_ptr` as is.  Linker errors are tolerable, UB is not.  Otherwise I can't follow the "you don't pay for what you don't use" paradigm of C++ by pulling in `ptr_base_incomplete` and its associated baggage

Comment: I ended up incorporating a macro as a non-default optional workaround in case this particular issue comes up for someone in the future.  I made a few more changes based on your other feedback and posted to my github.  https://github.com/clunietp/value_ptr  Overall, I feel the code is much improved due to your feedback, thank you!

Comment: @Tom: "Linker errors are tolerable; UB is not." The linker error in this case is a symptom of UB. You could hide the UB better by eliminating the mangling issue; let's say, by smuggling the `value_ptr` inside a `std::function` or a `std::any`. I have only a vague idea of how to do that, though, and am not super motivated to pursue it. (EDIT: Oh wait! Or smuggle it as a member of a `struct`, duh! Maybe I'll work that up later and post it here.)

Comment: @Tom: Here's the same UB but without the linker error. Now the UB manifests as the same `p.count` field having two different values in the two different translation units. https://wandbox.org/permlink/qZLGs8FyfMsx9g7d And we could easily turn that into a segfault if we wanted; agreed?

Comment: Genius.  So the variable size of `value_ptr` is what's killing me here, and its very clear the current `value_ptr` is fatally flawed.  I think I'm going to have to break up `value_ptr` into two use cases, `value_ptr` and `value_ptr_incomplete`, with some static assert/template wizardry to protect against cases like this.  Do you foresee that as sufficiently resolving this problem, and can you think of any other alternatives (aside from deriving from the same base)?  Thank you!!

Comment: I still might not understand the problem you're trying to solve, but I think you should just provide *one* of `value_ptr<T>` or `value_ptr_incomplete<T>`. If the former, then you have a precondition that `T` must be a complete type (just like e.g. `std::optional<T>` does). If the latter, then you would design the type so that `T` didn't have to be a complete type (as e.g. `std::vector<T>` does, more or less). I wouldn't bother making both flavors unless I foresaw a specific need for both flavors.